# Gmail API Users.Messages GET metadataHeaders Format

Tags: python, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am working in python and trying to perform a GET call to the [Gmail API Users.Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

```
wantedItems = {'X-Original-To','Message-ID','Date','Delivered-To'}
message = GetMessage(gmail_service,'me',id,'metadata',wantedItems)
```

Currently, performing this call, I do not get any headers. How do I format `wantedItems` so that I get the proper response from the API?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518926/metadataheaders-option-failing-with-multiple-headers

Comment: I have tried that, and every combination of such, and it doesn't work for me. I am looking for the specific proper formatting of the string and not just a theory of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a list:

```
from apiclient import discovery

... credentials setup omitted

http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
resource = service.users().messages()

mail_id = '<mail-id>'
headers = ['X-Original-To','Message-ID','Date','Delivered-To']
result = resource.get(userId = 'me',
                      id = mail_id,
                      format = 'metadata',
                      metadataHeaders = headers).execute()
print(result)
```